# Can I use " the problem got solved"?

Tags: grammar

In context, I reported an online problem and in response the the service executive did her job but was not sure about whether hr action had solved the problem, so she asked me whether my problem was solved. In answer to that, could I correctly have said "the problem got solved"?

Comment: Yes, you can say that, and it will be understood and is grammatically correct. But it might be more friendly to tell her that yes, *she solved* the problem.

Answer (score 3):

"The problem is solved."

"Yes, the problem is solved."

"Thank you, you have solved the problem."

"Thanks, you've solved my problem."

Any of those phrases will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "The problem was solved".

Comment: Could you explain why you would say this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `The problem has been solved`.

Comment: Why would you suggest this?